# Hide vscode menu items using 'Custom CSS and JS Loader' extension

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

I want to disable the "Commit All", and "Commit All (amend)" and "Commit All (signed off)" menu options in vscode's source control tab. The vscode team is not receptive to that: [(1)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76510), [(2)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83707). My reasoning is the same as in those issues.

[image]

I installed the ["Custom CSS and JS Loader"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) vscode extension. I'm using it for various tweaks, it works.

Those menu items are within the three dot menu in the anchor: `#workbench\.view\.scm > div > div > div.monaco-scrollable-element > div.split-view-container > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.pane-header.expanded > div.actions > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(6) > div > div > a`.

But I don't know how to get at the menu that seems to be dynamically created when clicking that button.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a direct solution for your problem, which isn't based on "Custom CSS and JS Loader" `vscode` extension.

The part of code for building the menu is:

```
git.commit": [
        {
          "command": "git.commit",
          "group": "1_commit@1"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStaged",
          "group": "1_commit@2"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAll",
          "group": "1_commit@3"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.undoCommit",
          "group": "1_commit@4"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.rebaseAbort",
          "group": "1_commit@5"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitNoVerify",
          "group": "1_commit@6",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStagedNoVerify",
          "group": "1_commit@7",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAllNoVerify",
          "group": "1_commit@8",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStagedAmend",
          "group": "2_amend@1"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAllAmend",
          "group": "2_amend@2"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStagedAmendNoVerify",
          "group": "2_amend@3",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAllAmendNoVerify",
          "group": "2_amend@4",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStagedSigned",
          "group": "3_signoff@1"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAllSigned",
          "group": "3_signoff@2"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitStagedSignedNoVerify",
          "group": "3_signoff@3",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.commitAllSignedNoVerify",
          "group": "3_signoff@4",
          "when": "config.git.allowNoVerifyCommit"
        }
      ],
```

It's inside `vscode/extensions/git/package.json` file in sources.

1. You can modify it either by removing the options you want to remove, or by adding a "when" condition (or extending the existing) with a new settings, say "config.git.allowCommitAll".
2. You can also directly modify the built file, it's under `<Microsoft VS Code>\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js`.
3. In some cases you'd also have to modify the cache, it's under `<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensions\builtin` in Windows (root cache for Mac is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/` and for Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/`)

Comment: I prefer to use that extension and not change any config or rebuild the app. But I'm sure some people will appreciate it, so thank you for this. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @lonix for the appreciation. Just a little comment, you said *I prefer to use that extension and not change any config*. The [Disclaimer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#:~:text=Disclaimer,your%20own%20risk.) for "Custom CSS and JS Loader" says: *This extension modifies some Visual Studio Code files so use it at your own risk*.

Comment: lol yes you are right! But the extension handles all that for me, I don't have to fiddle with it myself. Also, I'm now using a "better" one ([customize-ui](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui)) which requires no modifications from me at all, I just need to add the custom css/js to the `.vscode/settings.json`.

Comment: I suspect this cannot be done with an extension, so unless someone posts an answer for "Custom CSS and JS Loader" or "Customize-UI", I'm marking yours as the solution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. Yet some 50 cents which might help, I've extracted the structure from VS Code for the Web: https://pastebin.com/zRp9ji1W Good luck